# Combination of characters in an array with formula nPr in java

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, npr

Can someone please tell me how to implement combination for character values stored in an array with formula nPr.
For example if I have a set of {a,b,v,f} and I want to choose 2 at a time the answer should be {a,b} {a,v} {a,f} {b,v} {b,f} {v,f}.

Or any link if this problem has a solution on the web.
Thanks.

Comment: These (in your example) are combinations, in permutations you would also care about order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general implementation:

```
static <T> List<List<T>> combinations( List<T> list, int n ){

    List<List<T>> result;

    if( list.size() <= n ){

        result = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        result.add( new ArrayList<T>(list) );

    }else if( n <= 0 ){

        result = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        result.add( new ArrayList<T>() );

    }else{

        List<T> sublist = list.subList( 1, list.size() );

        result = combinations( sublist, n );

        for( List<T> alist : combinations( sublist, n-1 ) ){
            List<T> thelist = new ArrayList<T>( alist );
            thelist.add( list.get(0) );
            result.add( thelist );
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
list.add('a');
list.add('b');
list.add('c');
list.add('d');

List<List<Character>> combos = combinations( list, 2 );
```

Here's an [ideone](http://ideone.com/Akfpj).

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but your solution is not working well for list `{ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' }` and 3.

Comment: @Betlista sorry... that had a few bugs... that's what happens when you write out an algorithm without debugging it with a real compiler. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example I'm printing combinations:

```
public class PrintCombinations {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        // testing input 1
        int n = 2;
        char[] a = { 'a', 'b', 'v', 'f' };
        solve( n, a );

        // testing input 2
        n = 3;
        a = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };
        solve( n, a );

    }

    private static void solve( final int n, final char[] a ) {
        final int[] selected = new int[n];
        print( n, a, 0, selected );
    }

    // need to know how many items are selected - n, input array - a
    // item which can be selected next - from and already selected items
    private static void print( final int n, final char[] a, final int from, final int[] selected ) {
        if ( n == 0 ) { // all selected, just print them
            for ( int i = 0; i < selected.length; ++i ) {
                System.out.print( a[ selected[ i ] ] + " " );
            }
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        // select one and use recursion for others
        for ( int i = from; i < a.length; ++i ) {
            selected[ selected.length - n ] = i;
            print( n - 1, a, i + 1, selected );
        }
    }
}
```

But you have to realize, that number of combinations is [image: n over k is n!/k!*(n-k)!], so it is quite big number for example [image: 26 over 13 is 10400600] and printout 10 milions arrays will take a while...